# What is an LOE?

Tags: project-management

I have no idea, I Googled, no dice.

In context: "Do we have an LOE on this? They keep asking me haha. :)"

I have googled and googled and googled and can't put my hands around it. Could someone explain it to me like I'm five?

Comment: Why not just ask the person that's asking you?

Comment: A self-fulfilling acronym: Loss Of Expressiveness

Comment: Its Level Of Effort. We need to add number of days the task will take to complete.

Answer (score 6):

***Level Of Effort*** is the most likely one.  There are a bunch listed here as well: http://www.acronymfinder.com/Business/LOE.html

I guessed this one because it was in the context of project management, and that's the type of thing a PM needs to know.

And it specifically shows up here: http://www.all-acronyms.com/LOE/tag/project_management as the first Google result of a search for "LOE project management acronym"